# SAPUi5 Usage Grid and GridData

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to hide some controls on different screen sizes using a Grid and GridData Layout.

I want to use the properties visibleM, visibleS, visibleXL described in the documentation https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.layout.GridData.html, but they don't seem to work.

Here is the JSBin Sample code, trying to hide a Button Control with visibleM, visibleS properties.
http://jsbin.com/nugiri/edit?html,console,output

Something must be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({
                  span: 'XL6 L6 M6 S12',
                  visibleM : false

                })
```

Thanks finally that worked for me. I had a problem in the library.css The class ".sapUiRespGridHiddenM" which is set by the visibleM property was written with spaces ".sapUiRespGridHidden M". That was the reason why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In your JS Bin, please add quotes to false --> "false".

```
layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({
     visibleM : "false",
```

Comment: Wen i add quotes i get an error. "error"
"h.prototype.validateProperty@https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:473:736
h.prototype.setProperty@https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:471:69
P.prototype.generate/<@https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:551:134
h.prototype.applySettings@https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:468:1365
h<.constructor/<@https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:461:896

Comment: oh wow, you are correct. What was i thinking. This must indeed be a boolean offcoure! If i remove the quotes, set it to false (and only leave visibleM in) and then run the example in full screen mode (small arrow next to auto-run JS) you can see that when resizing the window, the button appears and disappers real-time when hitting different sizes. So your original code must have been correct.

Comment: Thanks finally that worked for me. I had a problem in the library.css The class ".sapUiRespGridHiddenM" which is set by the visibleM property was written with spaces ".sapUiRespGridHidden M". That was the reason why it didn't work.